# Do variable selection algorithms and hypotheses testing for coefficients (in MLR) do the same thing, and when/what is better?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, lasso

If hypothesis testing for coefficients in an MLR setting is powerful, why would we use a variable selection algorithm instead? For example, would you use hypothesis testing to find if the estimated coefficients of LASSO regression are significant?

Comment: "If method A us powerful, why use method B?" Maybe B is also powerful. And what is certain: The resulting models are all based.

Answer (score 2):

One way of using hypothesis testing for model building is to run simple regressions with each potential independent variable and keep those that are significant for a multiple regression.  This is known as bivariate screening and, while it is relatively common, it isn't good. The results for the final model will be wrong. P values will be too low, standard errors too small, and parameter estimates biased away from 0.

In addition, automatic methods of model building all have a few faults. These have been discussed here many times, but two of the biggest are a) that they won't find variables that do not have strong or significant relationships with the dependent variable but serve as valuable covariates and b) They stop the researcher from thinking.